# How to use global variables in outside of function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, global

I can't access the variable outside the function in JavaScript.

JavaScript code:

```
 var latitude;
 var longitude;
 function hello()
   {
   for(var i=0;i<con.length;i++)
   {
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': con[i]}, function(results, status) 
   {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        });
         alert(latitude);    //here it works well
   }
   }
   alert(latitude);      //here i am getting error: undefined
```

How can I use the variable outside the function?

Comment: `geocode` is an async function - you need to use a callback

Comment: Actually, you can access the `latitude,longitude` variables, they just haven't been set when your `hello` function exits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you try to output variables before you get result from the server (`geocode` is async function). It is wrong way. You only can use them in geocode function:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': con[i]}, function(results, status)  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    }
    <--- there
});
```

Or you can use callback function:

```
var latitude;
var longitude;

function showResults(latitude, longitude) {
    alert('latitude is '+latitude);
    alert('longitude is '+longitude);
}

function hello()
{
    for(var i=0;i<con.length;i++)
    {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': con[i]}, function(results, status)  {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                latitude=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            }
            alert(latitude);    //here it works well
            showResults(latitude, longitude);
        });
    }
}
```

But it is same.

Also, it looks like you have some mistakes with format. I updated code a bit. Now brackets ) and } are in correct place. Correct me if I am wrong.

Anyway, it is good practise to format your code. I was thinking about your brackets about 2 minutes. You have to use correct format.

Comment: Thank u @sharikov ...I want to use latitude and longitude variable outside of function hello() and showResults() as a string can you help me how to get latitude and longitude values outside of functions.

Comment: As I said, you can use one of these methods only. Try to find post there on so: how to get Ajax response